# Can 3 people fuse using the potara earrings?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

Consider the following scenario.

We have Goku, Vegeta and Trunks. Amongst the 3 they have 2 pairs of potara earrings.

Can Goku and Vegeta fuse using 1 pair of potara earrings and then using the other pair of earrings can Vegito and Trunks fuse ?

I understand potara earrings can only be used once in a lifetime, but here we have 2 pairs of potara earrings. So does the rule still apply ? If it does then Goku and Vegeta both use the potara twice, once in the buu saga and now in the next DBS episode. Or does this mean that Goku can only now fuse with Vegeta using the potara earrings ?

Comment: Even if they can, I don't think that that is a good idea. It would be hard for 3 person to control one body. Their battle potential would get hindered by excessive coordination necessary between the 3.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research to be sure, I came to the conclusion that there is simply nothing that proves or disproves this possibility. The potara may retain their power to fuse people multiple times over, or just as likely may not.